# Stuck: [Remote - SSH 0.49.0] Setting up SSH Host DEV: (details) Initializing VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have successfully used the vscode's extension Remote-SSH on a few remote linux servers. However, I cannot get past the "Acquiring lock" message in my vscode terminal on one particular server and would like to know how to. The terminal displays the "Acquiring Lock" line in the terminal and nothing else follows. I have even let this connection try to resolve itself overnight and it just will not go any further.

The output I am receiving appears as follows (I have replaced some real values/hash with generic text wrapped in angle brackets):

```
[13:48:34.210] Log Level: 3
[13:48:34.218] remote-ssh@0.49.0
[13:48:34.218] win32 x64
[13:48:34.221] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+<hash>", attempt 1
[13:48:34.221] SSH Resolver called for host: DEV
[13:48:34.221] Setting up SSH remote "DEV"
[13:48:34.291] Using commit id "<hash>" and quality "stable" for server
[13:48:34.292] Install and start server if needed
[13:48:34.296] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:48:34.347] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[13:48:34.348] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 55214 DEV bash
[13:48:34.354] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[13:48:34.502] > 
[13:48:34.503] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:48:34.626] > <User>@<HostName>'s password:
[13:48:34.626] Showing password prompt
[13:48:42.869] Got password response
[13:48:42.869] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***********"
[13:48:42.908] > 
> 
[13:48:42.969] > <hash>: running
> 
[13:48:43.009] > Acquiring lock on /<path to commit id hash>/vscode-remote-lock.<User>.<hash>
>  
>
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Vscode version

```
Version: 1.42.1 (user setup)
Commit: c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054
Date: 2020-02-11T14:45:59.656Z
Electron: 6.1.6
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Remote - SSH version 0.49.0

Thank you for taking a look at my issue!

**Update**
The attempt appears to have finally timed out. The message that was left is:

```
[15:48:54.081] "install" terminal command done
[15:48:54.082] > Connection reset by <ip address> port 22
> 
[15:48:54.084] Install terminal quit with output: Acquiring lock on <vscode-remote-lock file>
[15:48:54.085] Received install output: Acquiring lock on <vscode-remote-lock file>
[15:48:54.090] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: Acquiring lock on <vscode-remote-lock file>
[15:48:54.090] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[15:48:54.092] Resolver error: 
[15:48:54.108] ------
```

Comment: I brought this issue up on the Remote-SSH Github project: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2472 After putting this issue in on Stackoverflow, the extension developers have developed a fix for this on their Nightly version of the extension. The fix will be in the Remote-SSH version 0.50.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem today, and I solved it in a different way:

1. Open your server terminal and find a directory named ".vscode-server" which should be at the path `/home/<username>/.vscode-server`. It is hidden on most OS's, so you may have to search for it with `ls -a`.
2. Remove it with `rm -rf /home/<username>/.vscode-server/`
3. Reconnect your server with VS Code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try that out sometime. Since I installed the Nightly version, I haven't had any issues.

Comment: Resolved the issue for me running VS Code version `1.79.2` w/ Remote-SSH `v0.102.0`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I brought this issue up on the Remote-SSH Github project: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2472

After putting this issue in on Stackoverflow, the extension developers have developed a fix for this on their Nightly version of the extension. The fix will be in the Remote-SSH version 0.50.